# How do I save this object to a file?

Tags: c#, interop, ms-word

I have some word documents with objects inside them. I am testing one that has 3 pdf-files (the wordApp.Selection.InlineShapes.Count matches this), But else I have trouble getting any info from the objects. How do I save it to a disk? Any help is appreciated, because the inlineShape.OLEFormat.IconLabel is an empty string in all 3 instances.

```
        var wordApp = new Word.Application();
        object confirmConversions = false;
        object readOnly = true;

        object missing = Type.Missing;
        this.document = wordApp.Documents.Open(
            ref fn, ref confirmConversions, ref readOnly,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing);

        string applicationName = null;

        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape inlineShape in this.document.InlineShapes)
        {
            applicationName = inlineShape.OLEFormat.IconLabel;
        }
```

Comment: What about other `inlineShape` properties?

Comment: The properties do not have any useful info (filename, size, type, etc) as far as I can see.

Comment: Any particular reason you didn't just name it "Filename?" nondescriptive or nonintuitive variable names are the second root of all evil.

Comment: David: +1. For a second I thought they may have been passing a `Furious Neanderthal`, or something, to Word!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are open to using 3rd party controls, this can be easily accomplished using Aspose.Words:

```
         Aspose.Words.Document d = new Document(@"C:\users\john\desktop\embeddedPDF.docx");
        foreach (Aspose.Words.Drawing.Shape shp in d.GetChildNodes(NodeType.Shape, true))
        {
        shp.OleFormat.Save(@"C:\Temp\testoutput.pdf");
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a snippet from a post which I found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/85ef2249-0344-42f5-8dec-e7c09f98c62b/) which explains the approach you need to take in order to do this:

> Any file that can be embedded in a
>   document as an OLE object can be
>   extracted.  However, we may not be
>   able to provide you with a simple code
>   example if the technology doesn't
>   belong to us (such as Adobe Acrobat
>   files).
>
> What we are doing with Office objects
>   is activating the object and then
>   taking advantage of the exposed
>   IDispatch interface so that we can use
>   COM interop to communicate directly
>   with the object's programming model. 
>   As it happens, the Office applications
>   generally expose SaveAs methods that
>   we can call to save the files in
>   question. Going through the Office
>   programming model in this fashion is a
>   handy shortcut that enables saving
>   embedded objects with very little
>   code.
>
> I suspect that Adobe Acrobat exposes a
>   similar programming model because
>   there is an Adobe Acrobat Type
>   Library.  You will have to browse the
>   Type Library to see if it exposes some
>   sort of Save or Save as method.  If it
>   does, you can add it as a reference to
>   your project (via the COM References
>   tab of the Add Reference dialog in
>   Visual Studio) and take a similar
>   approach as Ji suggests in his post
>   above.
>   [(continues...)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/85ef2249-0344-42f5-8dec-e7c09f98c62b/)

Comment: Thank you. Just as I feared. This really sucks.